# Get reference for the current content site being viewed

Tags: servicenow

So I came to a situation where I need to know `sys_id` of the content site of a ui page currently being viewed by the user

I was thinking to get the current request URL and extract suffix part then look up `content_site` table, however it's not a very clean solution and some people may apply URL rewriting rules which would change the URL, so any ideas?

I mean how service now relates different properties and components to the root content site?

I'm running on Helsinki version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain a little more of what you're trying to accomplish and possibly where you're trying to look this up?

If you're trying to get the `sys_id` of the *Content Site* when looking at a page, you can pull it in *Jelly* script such as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:g2="null" xmlns:j2="null" trim="false">
   <body>
       <script language="javascript">
          var siteSysId = "${current_page.getSiteID()}";
          alert("Site sys_id: " + id);
       </script>
   </body>
</j:jelly>
```

The key part is `${current_page.getSiteID()}` which will get you the value.

I've not had much luck finding good documentation of the `current_page` object, but may get you started.

I tested this on a *Geneva* instance, so I suspect it'll work on *Helsinki*

Comment: thanks for your response, I'll test it now and give you feed back

Comment: this is what I was exactly looking for, thanks kirk, in response to your question, I was asked to add some custom fields to the content site and based on the values of these custom fields I'll do sth in a content page, so I needed to access the content site record to fetch required values, problem solved!